# Receive json object through ajax post request

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

> UNABLE TO DETECT PROBLEM

**I am trying to get data from server using ajax post request but when ajax request hits back end c# method its data part gets null**

here is my js code

```
 let da = '{"sidx":'+sid+',"idx":'+cur+'}';
    da = JSON.parse(da);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../RegSaleman/next",
        data: {x:da},
        datatype: "Json",
        complete: function (dataret) {




        }
    });
```

and c# code is

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult next(JsonResult x)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Try replacing the param type from JsonResult to string

Comment: What is your `JsonResult` model? And its just `data: { sidx: sid, idx: cur }` assuming `JsonResult` contains those 2 properties

Comment: Yes that work when we use json.stringify  but i want to receive  throght any c# json class

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm thinking he's trying to pass the JsonResult mvc action result.  Which will never work.

Comment: Jsonresult is not modal  it is a C# built in class

Comment: @Fran, That makes no sense :)

Comment: No there is no involvement of action result @Fran

Comment: i have debugged this  When it hits the method and i  hover over x then the data property of x is null.

Comment: There is no C# "json" class.  json is just a serialization format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to read JsonResult, which is wrong. This class used for *response* from server.
You can create some data model (simple class) that will be mapped automatically by MVC framework.
Let's assume that you have JSON object:

```
{
   "id": "someValue",
   "foo" : 3,
   "bar" : "bar string"
}
```

and you can create a class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public int Foo {get;set;}
    public string Bar {get;set;}
}
```

As you can see, it even can map variables in different case (like Foo and "foo"), but this behavior could be altered in case of need.
And your method will be:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult next(MyClass x)
{

}
```

Comment: yes that will work. but  i was just trying to find a c# class that automatically get maped according to json object is there any ?

Comment: You can send as string and then you deserialize the Json string using newtonsoft.json:

var  jsonConverted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object>(jsonString);

Comment: Ohmmmmm some close .Thanks                                                                                      There is no other way except string ?

Comment: But there is any reason why it can't be string? Because when you send to the class from ajax, it will try to convert to the type that you inform, so if you try **string** , it will get the json as you are sending **'{"sidx":'+sid+',"idx":'+cur+'}'**   and then using deserialize, you will already be able to use each key, so you could call sidx as **jsonConverted["sidx"].toString()** and you would get the value that you passed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var obj = new Object();

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/RegSaleman/next",
    data: JSON.stringify(o),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {


    },
    failure: function (response) {

    },
    error: function (response) {

    }
});
```

Comment: The question is about the receive side (server side), not the send side (client side).